# Spring Boot 2 with Bucket4j to prevent DDOS Attacks

Tags: spring-boot, ddos, rate-limiting

I would like to prevent DDOS attacks on my spring boot 2 web application and I came across the framework `bucket4j` ([bucket4j-github](https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter)). My application will run on heroku, and there they suggested doing so ([Heroku-Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-production-on-heroku#rate-limit-api-calls))

So far so good. I am now trying to implement `bucket4j` and I would expect after that, in case I press `F5` very fast and frequent, something would happen, an error will occure or something like that. But it behaves as it would without the `bucket4j` framework, the request has been all answered.

My target is to limit the rate from an ip. Currently I just tried from localhost.

What I have so far:

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- Somehow I needed that since bucket4j--> 
        <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
# CACHE
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml

# RATE LIMIT
bucket4j.enabled=true
bucket4j.filters[0].cache-name=buckets
bucket4j.filters[0].filter-method=servlet
bucket4j.filters[0].url=/* 
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].capacity=10
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].time=1
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].unit=minutes
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].expression=getRemoteAddress()
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval=0
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval-unit=minutes
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<config ... >
    <cache alias="buckets">
        <expiry><ttl unit="seconds">3600</ttl></expiry>
        <heap unit="entries">1000000</heap>
    </cache>
</config>
```

What am I missing, or did I missunderstand the framework? Thanks for hints.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Hi, I am currently working on another project. This here is still on my todo. I did not try out yet more. But I will come back here, when I worked on it.

Comment: Hi @michael-hegner, did you solve the problem? I have a similar issue and did not find the soludion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216856/how-to-use-spring-boot-bucket4j-library

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to **change** this line to :

```
bucket4j.filters[0].url = .*
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@EnableCaching` in my Spring Boot configuration and using  `bucket4j.filters[0].url=.*` was enough to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure maven is importing the dependency.
Adding the version number in pom.xml solved the problem for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

By not adding the version number in pom.xml maven was not importing the dependency. No errors were showing but the rate limiting was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing in application.properties and working for me, you can try this!

```
#This is for Api Rate Limit
#Reference -: https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter#bucket4j-properties
spring.cache.type=jcache
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
bucket4j.enabled=true
bucket4j.filters[0].cache-name=buckets
bucket4j.filters[0].filter-method=servlet
bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-body={ "message": "Too many requests" }
bucket4j.filters[0].url=.*
bucket4j.filters[0].strategy=first
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].expression=getRemoteAddr()
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].capacity=10
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].time=1
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].unit=minutes
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval=0
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval-unit=minutes
```

and dont forget to add `@EnableCaching` in any `@Configuration` file

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration works for me:

**1) pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**2) ehcache.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd">
<cache alias="buckets">
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">3600</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">1000000</heap>
</cache>
```

**3) application.properties**

```
### Bucket4j
bucket4j.enabled=true
bucket4j.filters[0].cache-name=buckets
bucket4j.filters[0].filter-method=servlet
bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-body={ "message": "Too many requests" }
bucket4j.filters[0].url=.*
bucket4j.filters[0].strategy=first
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].capacity=10
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].time=1
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].unit=minutes
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval=0
bucket4j.filters[0].rate-limits[0].bandwidths[0].fixed-refill-interval-unit=minutes

### Ehcache
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

Make sure `@EnableCaching` is added in your configuration or main class.

Answer (score 0):

Here follows my single configuration class that prevents DOS attacks:

```
import io.github.bucket4j.Bandwidth;
import io.github.bucket4j.Bucket;
import io.github.bucket4j.Refill;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Configuration
public class HttpSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final Map<String, Bucket> cache;

    public HttpSecurityConfig() {
        cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
                String IPAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
                System.out.println("Remote Address: " + IPAddress);

                updateCache(IPAddress);

                if (!isRequestRateOk(IPAddress)) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateCache(String IPAddress) {
        cache.putIfAbsent(IPAddress,
                Bucket.builder()
                    .addLimit(Bandwidth.classic(5, Refill.intervally(5, Duration.ofMinutes(1)))) // Set your request rate limit
                    .build());
    }

    private boolean isRequestRateOk(String IPAddress) {
        return cache.get(IPAddress).tryConsume(1);
    }
}
```

Dependency used: **bucket4j-core** https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j-core

**Reference**: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j